# Node js module return undefined

Tags: node.js

I have create controller and model using nodejs. When I try to access model function inside the controller. Its return undefined. Here is my sample code

### userController.js file

```
    var User = require('../models/user');
    // Display list of all Authors.
    exports.user_list = function(req, res) {
    var allUsers = User.allUser();
      console.log(allUsers); //It return undefined
      res.render("../views/users/index", {title : 'Users Listing'});
   };
```

### model/user.js

```
  var config = require('./../config');
  var User = {
    allUser: function () { 
         config.query("Select * from customer ", function (err, results, fields) {
          return results;
         });
     }
   };
   module.exports = User
```

### index.js file

```
    //Basic routing.
    var express = require( 'express' );
    var app = express();
    var config = require('./config');
    //Creating Router() object
    var router = express.Router();
    var user_controller = require('./controller/userController.js');
    router.get('/users', user_controller.user_list);
    //router.get('/users/:id/update', user_controller.user_detail);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use("/",router);
     /* app.use("*",function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/404.html");
     }); */
     // Listen to this Port
    app.listen(3000,function(){
       console.log("Live at Port 3000");
     });
    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not passing a callback argument to the `User.allUser()` call in userController.js

Try calling it like this:

```
var allUsers = User.allUser(console.log);
```

It should print out your results.

Comment: I have used it will print out result but allUsers is also undefined

Comment: Ok, so now you need to replace `console.log` by a function that returns your results if you need to do something before returning your data, or just get rid of the  callback variable all together and replace the line `return callback(results)` by `return results`.

Comment: I have changed the return type but already getting same error. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I think your naming is just off.

In userController.js file: var User = require('../**models**/user');

However your file path is: **model**/user.js

Also i'm assuming based on the code userController.js is located in the controller directory.

```
yourproject
|-- controller
|   `-- userController.js
|-- model
|   `-- user.js      
|-- config.js
|-- index.js
`-- package.json
```

Comment: When I change the path it will generate error Cannot find module

Comment: What is the solution

Comment: @alnitak  can you please answer this question

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I copied your code, correct the path to be   `var User = require('../model/user');` and was able to run just fine (had to comment out the query stuff but otherwise it works). If you are getting a Cannot find module error you need to verify whats causing the error and make sure the paths are correct you should see this in the error stack where its looking for the module.